# Как передавать данные из 1 Activity в 2 Activity?

Tags: java, android

У меня есть 1 Activity я хочу передать данные в Presenter 2 Activity использую MVP.

MVP изучать недавно начал, мало что - знаю. В интернете просто не могу найти инфу о том как передавать значение используя MVP между Presenterми.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application

Comment: @RafaelOsipov, Там нет MVP. просто через Intent и я передать могу. Вопрос про Presenter

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, можете воспользоваться методом `onActivityResult()`
И к примеру у Вас есть в presenter'e метод который собирает данные, фильтрует, не важно.
Вам просто нужно будет его вызвать в удобном для Вас месте, к примеру при нажатии на системную кнопку back примерно следующим образом:

```
override fun onBackPressed(): Boolean {
    val intent = Intent().putExtra(KEY_ACCOUNT_GUID_LIST, presenter.getData())
    targetFragment?.onActivityResult(targetRequestCode, Activity.RESULT_OK, intent)
    return false
}
```